Time frame for topcoat over Zinsser BIN
I have applied Zinsser B.I.N to cabinets and recently read that top coat must be applied within 3 days before it completely cures. Im on day 3 and not able to paint today, using Valspar cabinet/furniture oil enriched enamel paint. Is this true? Or must I strip and start over? Thanks for you help!

The instructions for Zinsser BIN say that full cure of the primer happens in 1 to 3 days depending on circumstances. I don't see any indication in the Zinsser instructions that the next coating has to be applied within those 1-3 days.
The Valspar instructions may have information on the age of primer to be covered, or what to do if the primer coat is "old".
FWIW, back in my cabinet shop days, the finishing crew had to scuff-sand with high-grit (220, 320) sandpaper on primed surfaces if the paint coating wasn't applied within a certain amount of time.
